# Inject a foreign object into a formula?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Formulae often use ranges ,e.g.

```
=If(A1=2,"Yes","No")
```

In this example `A1` is injected with the `Range` object which represents cell `A1`. But let's say I have some object, from some class. How would I inject this into a formula?

At the moment my best bet (which is rather awful) is to use a collection and UDF:

```
Public FormulaVariables as Collection
Public Function getVar(key as string) as object
  set getVar = FormulaVariables(key)
end function
Public Sub addVar(key as string, obj as object)
  if FormulaVariables is nothing then set FormulaVariables = new Collection
  FormulaVariables.add obj,key
end sub
```

Such that I can call `addVar("someCoolId",myObject)` and then use formula like:

```
=If(checkSomething(getVar("someCoolId")),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function) is the name of a built in VBA function. I'd use a different name. That said, why do you need to do this from the formula? Can't you just wrap it like `checkSomething(foo As String)`?

Comment: @Comintern Mainly because I'm not actually using it as formulae, lol. I'm transpiling existing code to formulae and executing it using excel's formulae runtime. I thought that was easier than writing my own interpreter... And ultimately, I need a dynamic system which users can use.

Comment: Seems a reasonable approach. Your "Foreign object" in this case is a collection, but it could be anything right? It's all up to your `getVar()` UDF to make excel UI and VBA both happy. You'll have to be more specific about your question though if you need answer besides "Seems reasonable".

Comment: Also, and it'a bit of a quibble, there is no "Injection of a foreign object into a cell formula" so that return of an "Object" in your formula isn't going to fly. Cell formulas can deal with ranges but really it requires as a return from that range a value or array of values (depending on the context). The same would be true as the return from your UDF `getvar()` where it will return a value or an array. Your UDF here would just be the middleman between the object and limited type of return that a formula can handle.

Comment: [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/frequently-asked-questions-about-excel-services-udfs#data-types) about allowed return types from a UDF.

Comment: @JNevill I mainly wondered if there was a barely documented, but actually implemented way of doing it, rather than via the UDF. Stack overflow is often a good place for that. Thanks for the links though :)

Comment: 2 days on in actually trying to implement my suggested technique and it doesn't work at all. Trying to use `getVar(...)` returns `Error 2029`... This is why you test your stuff before you assume it works I guess...